# XML Serializtation in VB

Tags: xml, xml-serialization

I have a class "Product". Each Product has a Name. It consists of a list of "Widgets". Each Widget has a Number. Each Widget consists of a list of Widgets again (variable depth). At the very end there is one or multiple "Sockets", each of which has a SocketID and a Length. In other words, the last Widget does not consist of yet another Widget but of Sockets. The XML output I want looks something like [this](http://screencast.com/t/n4HZQuXhZJp).

I have tried any trick I could think of to define my class Product for serialization (ArrayList, List(of Widget), XMLInclude, etc. to achieve that result - no success. Has anybody run into this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

here you can list properties of a class (Object) and their values. so aftar this step you only needs to save them in a simple text file with your favorite format.

```
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

#Region " Windows Form Designer generated code "

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call

    End Sub

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            If Not (components Is Nothing) Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    Friend WithEvents lvwProperties As System.Windows.Forms.ListView
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.lvwProperties = New System.Windows.Forms.ListView
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'lvwProperties
        '
        Me.lvwProperties.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        Me.lvwProperties.FullRowSelect = True
        Me.lvwProperties.HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.Nonclickable
        Me.lvwProperties.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.lvwProperties.Name = "lvwProperties"
        Me.lvwProperties.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(292, 273)
        Me.lvwProperties.Sorting = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending
        Me.lvwProperties.TabIndex = 0
        Me.lvwProperties.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleBaseSize = New System.Drawing.Size(5, 13)
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(292, 273)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.lvwProperties)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Properties"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub

#End Region

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Make column headers.
        lvwProperties.Columns.Clear()
        lvwProperties.Columns.Add("Property", 10, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        lvwProperties.Columns.Add("Type", 10, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        lvwProperties.Columns.Add("Value", 10, HorizontalAlignment.Left)

        ' List the properties.
        ' Use the class you want to study instead of Form1.
        Dim property_value As Object
        Dim properties_info As PropertyInfo() = _
            GetType(Form1).GetProperties()
        lvwProperties.Items.Clear()
        For i As Integer = 0 To properties_info.Length - 1
            With properties_info(i)
                If .GetIndexParameters().Length = 0 Then
                    property_value = .GetValue(Me, Nothing)
                    If property_value Is Nothing Then
                        ListViewMakeRow(lvwProperties, _
                            .Name, _
                            .PropertyType.ToString, _
                            "<Nothing>")
                    Else
                        ListViewMakeRow(lvwProperties, _
                            .Name, _
                            .PropertyType.ToString, _
                            property_value.ToString)
                    End If
                Else
                    ListViewMakeRow(lvwProperties, _
                        .Name, _
                        .PropertyType.ToString, _
                        "<array>")
                End If
            End With
        Next i

        ' Size the columns to fit the data.
        lvwProperties.Columns(0).Width = -2
        lvwProperties.Columns(1).Width = -2
        lvwProperties.Columns(2).Width = -2

        ' Size the form.
        Dim new_wid As Integer = 30
        For i As Integer = 0 To lvwProperties.Columns.Count - 1
            new_wid += lvwProperties.Columns(i).Width
        Next i
        Me.Size = New Size(new_wid, Me.Size.Height)
    End Sub

    ' Make a ListView row.
    Private Sub ListViewMakeRow(ByVal lvw As ListView, ByVal item_title As String, ByVal ParamArray subitem_titles() As String)
        ' Make the item.
        Dim new_item As ListViewItem = lvw.Items.Add(item_title)

        ' Make the sub-items.
        For i As Integer = subitem_titles.GetLowerBound(0) To subitem_titles.GetUpperBound(0)
            new_item.SubItems.Add(subitem_titles(i))
        Next i
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: you can run this code directly to see the windows form, or copy not-auto-generated part to your own function. vote up and mark as best answer if it was useful 4u